# How to create a transaction with a custom script?

Tags: transactions, script

Is there a step-by-step tutorial or any documentation covering how to create a transaction that is not a standard `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`?

It seems very odd that there is absolutely no documentation or information covering how to create a transaction like this, when it is one of Bitcoin's greatest advantages.

Maybe a link to some open-source software which creates custom script transactions would be helpful. I don't know of any that exist off hand though.

Comment: As long as no `"; drop table wallet;"` is possible.

Comment: Little Bobby Tables, is that you?!

Comment: Don't most nodes reject custom scripts? That's what [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/)'s "strange transactions" are, right?

Comment: As far as I know, only transactions containing the "disabled" opcodes found here are rejected by nodes: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

Comment: Maybe this Node.js tool can help https://github.com/jgarzik/txtool

Comment: have a look at bitcore-lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using Python to accomplish this. [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) have what you need to be able to **deserialize** a hex transaction to JSON, and manipulate that and then **serialize** again to be able to sign and broadcast via support for blockchain.info.

This example will rebuild the standard script from the ground up:

```
>>> opdup = 0x76
>>> ophash160 = 0xA9
>>> push20 = 0x14
>>> opeqver = 0x88
>>> opchecksig = 0xAC
>>> pubkeyhash = 0x2dbde30815faee5bf221d6688ebad7e12f7b2b1a
```

We are going to [append hex values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629382/append-2-hex-values-in-python) by moving them bitwise.

- OP_DUP OP_HASH160 2dbde30815faee5bf221d6688ebad7e12f7b2b1a OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
- This is the [hex](https://coinb.in/decode-raw-transaction.html) we want **76a9142dbde30815faee5bf221d6688ebad7e12f7b2b1a88ac**

This is one way of doing it

```
>>> quickfix = 0xff
>>> asm = quickfix
>>> asm = asm << 8 | opdup
>>> asm = asm << 8 | ophash160
>>> asm = asm << 8 | push20
>>> asm = asm << 8*20 | pubkeyhash
>>> asm = asm << 8 | opeqver
>>> asm = asm << 8 | opchecksig
```

Ant then to check if its the same:

```
>>> almost = hex(asm)
>>> ready = almost.partition("0xff")[2]
>>> print(ready)
```

Hope this is what you are after :-)

Comment: there is a bug if 0x00 (OP_FALSE) is used, if we try to left shift that nothing will happen. a quick fix is to add 0xff first, and then remove it at the last step

Answer (score 1):

ABSOLUTELY Go!

```
import(
    "github.com/btcsuite/btcd/txscript"
    "github.com/btcsuite/btcd/wire"
)

tx := wire.NewMsgTx(2)
tx.AddTxOut(wire.NewTxOut(int64(*outputvalueFlag*1e8), script()))

func script() ([]byte) {
    script := txscript.NewScriptBuilder()
    script.AddInt64(1)
    script.AddData(bytes[0:65])
    script.AddInt64(1)
    script.AddOp(txscript.OP_CHECKMULTISIG)
    return script.Script()
}
...
```