# How to create output scripts?

Tags: script

How are output scripts created and how can you create your own scripts or is this only possible through creating a transaction?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/14055/38618

Comment: related to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72773/30668